# 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. (Mean Stack)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

Hello am currently writing a meanstack application, each time i run ng new client, it keeps reporting 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Any idea what's the problem thanks.Note i already ran npm install @angular/cli so i just need to run ng new client to get on my way.I am running the command on the node.js command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Hello aready found an answer to my question, instead of running npm install @angular/cli  just use npm install -g @angular/cli. Note the difference is that you need to install angular cli globally. thanks and hope anybody with same error finds luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows you can solve this problem editing the ".npmrc" adding this value: prefix=${APPDATA}\npm.

You can to find this file in "c:\Users\YOURUSERHERE". To view this file you need to display the hidden items.

After doing this, simply install the Angular and be happy.